# sed within AppleScript

Tags: regex, sed, applescript

I'm trying to use a regex in an AppleScript, to set two variables to different substrings of some text which is in the following format and on the system clipboard (though the text and URL can vary arbitrarily, and there will often be an empty line after the URL):

```
This is a webapge title
http://url.foo.com/
```

I want to assign the first line to `pageTitle`, and the second to `pageURL`, and ignore everything else. The AppleScript I thought would do this is:

```
set titleURL to the clipboard
set pageTitle to (do shell script "echo \"" & titleURL & "\" | sed -E 's#(.*)\\n(.*)\\n?#\\1#'")
set pageURL to (do shell script "echo \"" & titleURL & "\" | sed -E 's#(.*)\\n(.*)\\n?#\\2#'")
```

The regex does what I want [when I test it on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mV9dZ3/4), but the AppleScript returns the entire string, untouched, for both variables. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is `grep` an option? `grep "[\w+]"` and `grep "http:/"`?

Comment: Are you aware of pbcopy and pbpaste, which allow you to access the clipboard within a shell script? Using pbpaste, you could get the clipboard contents and do the sed work completely within a shell script so that the escaping issues that arise when going between AppleScript and shell are avoided. That separate shell script file could then be the subject of your `do shell script` rather than trying to perform the entire shell script within AppleScript.

Comment: A combo of your suggestion and @jmunsch's works perfectly :) Thanks! I'll add the answer with credits.

Comment: Actually, having done a bit more testing, I'm having problems getting `pbpaste | grep "https?:/"` to work. I can't figure out what AppleScript requires to parse these kinds of expressions.

Comment: Wondering what in my original question warrants a negative point. Would be helpful to know for the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get things working by simply setting `pageTitle` to the first line of the clipboard and `pageURL` to the second, with the help of `awk`:

```
set titleURL to the clipboard
set pageTitle to (do shell script "pbpaste | awk '{ if (NR==1) print $0 }'")
set pageURL to (do shell script "pbpaste | awk '{ if (NR==2) print $0 }'")
```

Not the most interesting or general of solutions, but it's perfect for my purposes. Thanks to @DavidRavetti and @jmunsch for their helpful suggestions.